# java callable statement help using package procedure

Tags: java, procedure, callable-statement

Currently i have this procedure under package that gets user_name when some selects user_id on web page but now i wanna change the format by adding ssn to the page so when some body selects user_id it loads user name as well as ssn on webpage textbox.. i am using callable statement to load data.. what can i change here to get both user name and ssn

```
    PROCEDURE get_User_name
  (
    return_code_out OUT VARCHAR2,
    return_msg_out OUT VARCHAR2,
    user_id_in IN user.user_id%TYPE,
    user_name_out OUT user.user_name%TYPE
  )
  IS

  BEGIN


    return_code_out := '0000';
    return_msg_out := 'OK';

    SELECT c.user_name INTO user_name_out 
      FROM user c
     WHERE c.user_id = user_in;

 END get_user_name;
```

and here is my load function

```
    public String load() {

        String retMsg = null;
        DbUtil db = null;
        java.sql.CallableStatement cstmt = null;

            try {
            db = new DbUtil();
            cstmt = db.prepareCall("{ call sample.PACK_USER.get_user_name(?, ?, ?, ?) }");

            cstmt.registerOutParameter(1,OracleTypes.VARCHAR);
            cstmt.registerOutParameter(2,OracleTypes.VARCHAR);
            cstmt.setString(3,this.getuserid());
            cstmt.registerOutParameter(4,OracleTypes.VARCHAR);

                cstmt.execute();

            if (cstmt.getString(1).equals(Constants.dbSuccess))
                myLog.log(myLog.INFORMATION, "UserBean.load() DB return code and message = " + retMsg);
            else {
                retMsg =  cstmt.getString(1) + " - " + cstmt.getString(2);
                myLog.log(myLog.ERROR, "UserBean.load() DB return code and message = " + retMsg);
            }

            this.setUserName(cstmt.getString(4));
return retMsg;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So that is change your procedure as Rajesh suggested (though it does depend on which database server you are using):

```
PROCEDURE get_User_name
( user_id_in IN user.user_id%TYPE, 
  user_name_out OUT user.user_name%TYPE,
  user_ssn_out  out user.ssn_type%TYPE ) IS

BEGIN

SELECT c.user_name, c.ssn 
  INTO user_name_out, ssn_out
  FROM user c
  WHERE c.user_id = user_in;

END get_user_name;
```

AND change the Java code as follows:

```
        cstmt = db.prepareCall("{ call sample.PACK_USER.get_user_name(?, ?, ?) }");

        cstmt.setString(1,this.getuserid());
        cstmt.registerOutParameter(2,OracleTypes.VARCHAR);
        cstmt.registerOutParameter(3,OracleTypes.VARCHAR);
        cstmt.execute();

        String userName = cstmt.getString(2);
        String ssnType = cstmt.getString(3);
```

Your existing error code would never work - you must handle errors by catching an SQLException somewhere.

Comment: Does it work if we do this SELECT c.user_name, c.ssn    INTO user_name_out, ssn_out .. what happens here.. c.user_name get assigned to user_name_out and c.ssn get assigned to ssn_out.. coz i am not getting any result back on java side.. plz help

Comment: I will amend my solution to show how you read the out parameters. In tidying up your code we removed some parameters so the `getString(4)` method no longer works and neglected to tell you.

Comment: oh - I should also add that `retMsg` was always going to be set to `0000 - OK`. You could hard code that now.

Answer (score 0):

The procedure would need to be changed to...

```
PROCEDURE get_User_name

( user_id_in IN user.user_id%TYPE, 
  user_name_out OUT user.user_name%TYPE,
  user_ssn_out  out user.ssn_type%TYPE ) IS

BEGIN

---return_code_out := '0000';  /*catch sql exception in java instead..*/
---return_msg_out := 'OK';     /*catch sql exception in java instead..*/

SELECT c.user_name, c.ssn 
  INTO user_name_out, ssn_out
  FROM user c
 WHERE c.user_id = user_in;

END get_user_name;
```

From your code, it looks like you want to return the error code and error message out from the procedure. Instead, use the try catch block to catch the sqlException in Java and take the necessary action.